# Анимация печатающегося текста

Tags: javascript, html, css3, svg, анимация

Вот html

```
<h1>Закажите <span>сейчас</span> ремонт принтера</h1>
```

Вот так получается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сделать анимацию печатающегося текста слова "СЕЙЧАС". Нужно чтобы слово "СЕЙЧАС" раскрывалось и закрывалось по циклу с определенным интервалом. Как это сделать?

Comment: Здесь посмотри:
https://wp-kama.ru/id_4721/pechatayuschiysya-tekst-na-ekrane-javascript.html

Comment: Хм.. Я уже отвечал на что-то такое...

Comment: Нужно чтобы слово "СЕЙЧАС" раскрывалось и закрывалось по циклу с определенным интервалом

Answer (score 7):

Вариант на CSS

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@700;900&display=swap');

h1 {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  font-size: 300%;
  color: #092f6e;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

h1 > span {
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  font-weight: 900;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}

h1 > span::after {
  content: '\Aс\Aсе\Aсей\Aсейч\Aсейча\Aсейчас\Aсейчас\Aсейчас'; 
  display: block;
  color: #12baa9;
  white-space: break-spaces;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  animation: TextPrint 4s steps(9, start) infinite;
}

@keyframes TextPrint {
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Закажите <span>сейчас</span><br>ремонт принтера</h1>
```

---

Написал "шаблонизатор" под код выше.
После "КОНВЕРТИРОВАНИЯ" просто копируете код из текстареа и заменяете его в `h1 > span::after` из кода выше.

```js
$('#con').on('click', Convert);

function Convert() {
  let w = $('#word').val().trim(), wt = '', wa = [], war, ds = Number($('#delay_s').val()), de = Number($('#delay_e').val()), s = $('#invert').prop('checked');
  for(let i = 0; i < w.length; i++) wa.push(i > 0 ? wa[i - 1] + w[i] : w[0]);
  let wac = wa.slice();
  if(ds > 0) wac = new Array(ds).fill(' ').concat(wa);
  if(de > 0) wac = wa.concat(new Array(de).fill(w));
  if(s) wac = wac.concat(wa.reverse());
  war = '\\A '+wac.join('\\A ');
  $('#demo').text(w).css({'--content': `'${war}'`, '--step': String(wac.length+1)});
  $('#res').text('content: \''+war+'\';\nanimation-timing-function: steps('+String(wac.length+1)+', start);');
}
Convert();
```

```css
#res {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  white-space: pre;
}

#demo {
  display: inline-block;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  font-weight: 900;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 40px;
}

#demo::after {
  content: var(--content, '\A D\A DE\A DEM\A DEMO');
  display: block;
  color: #12baa9;
  font: inherit;
  white-space: break-spaces;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  animation: TextPrint 4s steps(var(--step, 5), start) infinite;
}

@keyframes TextPrint {
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Настройка</legend>
  <label for="word">Текст который будет печатным</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="word" value="DEMO"><br><br>
  <label>Ожидание перед "набором текста" (шагов)</label><br>
  <input id="delay_s" type="number" min="0" value="0"><br><br>
  <label>Ожидание после "набора" (шагов)</label><br>
  <input id="delay_e" type="number" min="0" value="0"><br><br>
  <label>"Набрать" и "Стереть"</label><br>
  <input id="invert" type="checkbox"><br><br>
  <button id="con">КОНВЕРТИРОВАТЬ</button>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Результат</legend>
  <div>
    <div id="demo">DEMO</div>
  </div>
  <textarea id="res" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
</fieldset>
```

> Нужно чтобы слово "СЕЙЧАС" раскрывалось и закрывалось..

Тут это можно настроить

Comment: Про `jump-start` браузеры постарше не ведают, а вот `start`знают и стар и млад ;-)

Comment: С моноширинным шрифтом можно ещё пару эффектов добавить, но...

Comment: похоже в сторону svg нужно копать

Comment: Нужно чтобы слово "СЕЙЧАС" раскрывалось и закрывалось по циклу с определенным интервалом. А оно раскрывается и пропадает и потом раскрывается.

Comment: @Denis, дополнил ответ

Answer (score 5):

Нужно разделить слово на буквы и каждой задать дилей больше чем у предстоящей.

Самый простой пример:

```js
const letters = split(animatable)
setTimeout(() => letters.forEach(span => span.style.opacity = 1), 0)

function split(element) {
  element.style.wordBreak = 'break-word'

  const letters = element.innerText.split('').map((letter, i) => {
    const span = document.createElement('span')
    span.innerHTML = letter !== ' ' ? letter : '&nbsp;'
    span.style.opacity = 0
    span.style.transitionDelay = 0.1 * i + 's'
    return span
  })

  element.innerHTML = ''
  element.append(...letters)
  return letters
}
```

```html
<p id="animatable">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum iure labore illo ea, sapiente esse sint quaerat, aliquam, necessitatibus perferendis dignissimos blanditiis excepturi odit eos fugiat! Sequi qui libero distinctioLorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum iure labore illo ea, sapiente esse sint quaerat, aliquam, necessitatibus perferendis dignissimos blanditiis excepturi odit eos fugiat! Sequi qui libero distinctio..</p>
```

от него уже можно плясать и делать различные анимации.

```js
const letters = split(animatable)

let v = true
setInterval(() => {
  v = !v
  letters.forEach(span => span.style.opacity = +v)
}, 1000)

function split(element) {
  const letters = element.innerText.split('').map((letter, i) => {
    const span = document.createElement('span')
    span.innerHTML = letter !== ' ' ? letter : '&nbsp;'
    span.style.transitionDelay = 0.1 * i + 's'
    span.style.transitionDuration = '0.5s'
    return span
  })

  element.innerHTML = ''
  element.append(...letters)
  return letters
}
```

```html
<h1>Закажите <span id="animatable">сейчас</span> ремонт принтера</h1>
```

Comment: Нужно чтобы слово "СЕЙЧАС" раскрывалось и закрывалось по циклу с определенным интервалом

Answer (score 3):

Компактный вариант для моноширенного шрифта:

```css
h1 {
  font-family: monospace;
  line-height: 2em;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6ch;
  height: 2em;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
}

span::before {
  content: "";
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: -1ch;
  animation: shrink steps(7) 6s infinite;
}

@keyframes shrink {
  from { width: calc(100% + 1ch); }
  to { width: 0; }
}
```

```html
<h1>Закажите <span>сейчас</span> ремонт принтера</h1>
```

Comment: В FF работает некорректно - сначала пусто, а под конец анимации появляется слово целиком.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, исправлено.

Answer (score 3):

Да, с моноширинными шрифтом всё просто:

```css
h1 { font: bold 48px/1em 'Consolas', monospace; color: #092f71; }

span {
  display: inline-block; height: 1em; width: 0ch;
  overflow: hidden; margin-right: 6ch;
  vertical-align: top; color: #0fbca9;
  animation: shrink steps(6) 3s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes shrink {
  0%, 10% { width: 0ch; margin-right: 6ch; }
  40%, 100% { width: 6ch; margin-right: 0ch; }
}
```

```html
<h1>Закажите <span>сейчас</span><br>ремонт принтера</h1>
```

Или так:

```css
h1 { font: bold 48px/1em 'Consolas', monospace; color: #092f71; }

span {
  display: inline-flex; height: 1em; width: 0ch;
  overflow: hidden; vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 6ch; margin-left: 0ch; color: #0fbca9;
  animation: shrink steps(6) 4s infinite;
}

@keyframes shrink {
  0%, 5% {
    width: 0ch; margin-right: 6ch; margin-left: 0ch;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
  30%, 50% {
    width: 6ch; margin-right: 0ch;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
  51%, 70% {
    width: 6ch; margin-left: 0ch;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  95%, 100% {
    width: 0ch; margin-left: 6ch; margin-right: 0ch;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Закажите <span>сейчас</span><br>ремонт принтера</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вложить хвост в каждую букву, то можно их и скрывать на 1/6 с хвостиком:

```css
h1 {
  font-style: italic;
}

span {
  animation: blink-6 7s step-start infinite both;
}

.l1 { animation-delay: 0s; }
.l2 { animation-delay: 1s; }
.l3 { animation-delay: 2s; }
.l4 { animation-delay: 3s; }
.l5 { animation-delay: 4s; }
.l6 { animation-delay: 5s; }

@keyframes blink-6 {
      0% { opacity: 0; }
 16.667% { opacity: 0; }
 16.668% { opacity: 1; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<h1>Закажите <span class=l1>с<span class=l2>е<span class=l3>й<span class=l4>ч<span class=l5>а<span class=l6>с</span></span></span></span></span></span> ремонт принтера</h1>
```

PS: И ещё вариант - не то, но прикольно получилось и жалко удалять:

```css
span {
  animation: blink 6s steps(2) infinite;
}

.l1 { animation-delay: 0s; }
.l2 { animation-delay: 1s; }
.l3 { animation-delay: 2s; }
.l4 { animation-delay: 3s; }
.l5 { animation-delay: 4s; }
.l6 { animation-delay: 5s; }

@keyframes blink {
   0% { visibility: hidden; }
 100% { visibility: visible; }
}
```

```html
<h1>Закажите <span class=l1>с<span class=l2>е<span class=l3>й<span class=l4>ч<span class=l5>а<span class=l6>с</span></span></span></span></span></span> ремонт принтера</h1>
```

Comment: Действительно прикольно получилось. Хотел тебя давно спросить, когда копируешь твой ник для комментария, захватывается ромбик вместе с ником. Его надо удалять или с ним дойдет комментарий?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, вроде в обоих вариантах доходит, хотя я обычно лишние ромбы удаляю. А в большинстве случаев достаточно написать `@q` и дальше движок сам предложит.

Comment: бывает подхватывает движок, но иногда не подхватывает, **как здесь**, даже если есть твои ответы, комментарии. Только, что попробовал

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, тут мы вдвоём, так что он их ещё и вырезает, если написать.

Comment: ♦  Спасибо, понял

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, а ромбик оставляет ;)